# Generate a schedule for doubles with rotating partners

Tags: combinations, matching-theory, combinatorial-designs

So I want to set up a schedule of double matches: player A and B vs player C and D. I have a few constraints for setting it up:

- Each player plays exactly 4 times
- The scheme should be as fair as possible. With this I mean that I want to achieve that every player sees as many different other players as possible. I don’t want player A to see another player 2 times and another player 0 times. The difference should be at most 1 (if this is possible).

Is there an easy way to do this for $n$ players? There should be $n$ games. I did this bruteforce ish for n=5,8,10,12 players. Now I want to do 13 and 15 for example